# knockout: applying "keydown" action to an element within an 'if: " attribute

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Within my viewmodel's viewAttached (post DOM load) I have the following:

```
viewAttached: function () {
            $('.auth-input').keydown(function (e) {
                debugger;
                var check = auth.showRegistering();
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (code == 13 && auth.showRegistering()) {
                    alert("trying!");
                    auth.register();
                }
                else if (code == 13 && auth.showRegistering() == false) {
                    auth.logIn();
                }
            });
        },
```

This is working great for all fields except one that is hidden behind an if statement:

```
<input data-bind="value: email" class="span2 auth-input" type="text" placeholder="Email">
<input data-bind="value: password" class="span2 auth-input" type="password" placeholder="Password">
<!-- ko if: showRegistering -->
<input data-bind="value: passwordConfirm" class="span2 auth-input" type="password" placeholder="Password Confirm">
<!-- /ko -->
```

It seems like the keydown action recognizes the first two inputs because they're visible when the DOM loads, but the other field isn't initially visible.

Here's a stripped down fiddle to demonstrate what I'm trying:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/41/

Is there any way to catch the keypress in that third input?

Comment: Please never write `== true`, it’s redundant.

Comment: it was for my own sanity while developing, fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because the knockout 'if' binding prevents the passwordConfirm input from rendering until the model has been bound.

You can solve this by using knockout to bind the keydown event instead of using jquery.

Place this on your model:

```
OnKeyDown: function (data, e) {
    debugger;
    var check = auth.showRegistering();
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13 && auth.showRegistering()) {
        alert("trying!");
        auth.register();
    }
    else if (code == 13 && auth.showRegistering() == false) {
        auth.logIn();
    }
};
```

and modify your bindings like so:

```
<input data-bind="value: passwordConfirm, event: {keydown:OnKeyDown}" type="password" />
```

Comment: @meze - would you be concerned about your approach running that check every time a key is pressed in the app?  typing this message here would have gone through that check like 200 times; it seems wrong.  Thoughts?

Comment: @RodneyTrotter - I tried your approach but the inputs aren't accepting characters for some reason.  I hit 's' and the code is run correctly, but the field never shows 's'.  I'll see if I can get a fiddle to show this.

Comment: @meze - Absolutely...it's alot to do on a single keydown. Personally I would avoid doing this myself.

Comment: @SB2055 - Make sure you still have the 'value' binding on the element also...I have modified my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks Rodney.  It's working now - I had to do on keyup.  When you said you would avoid doing this - do you mean your approach, or mezes, or both?

Comment: The approach is sound. What I meant was that I would be careful to avoid doing alot of processing inside of a keyup or keydown handler. After looking at your code again I wouldn't be concerned. It doesn't appear to be doing anything too heavy.

Comment: @SB2055 `body` is just an example. You need to set it to a closer element. But since there's a better solution and a duplicate answer, let's wipe away that comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation if you aren't sure if a DOM element will exist. jQuery makes this very easy for you:

```
$(document.body).on('keydown', '.auth-input', function (e) {
    var code = e.which;
    if (code == 13) {
        alert("trying!");
    }
});
```

See here for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/45/

Also, use e.which to get the character code, as recommended in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/).

Comment: @meze its an alternative approach. Its not wrong, and not worth the downvote methinks, but whatever.

Comment: It's not an alternative approach. Knockout provides its own solution for knockout-managed elements. It's a hack if there's no other way.

Comment: @meze sometimes people like to handle events unobtrusively without using knockouts event bindings. It's not a hack, it's a different approach.